# Error "StorageDepositLimitExhausted" occurs when trying to mint

Tags: ink, error

Error "StorageDepositLimitExhausted" occurs when trying to mint

But I don't know why this error happens

The code is here

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
#![feature(min_specialization)]
        
#[openbrush::contract]
pub mod my_psp22 {
    
    // imports from openbrush
    use openbrush::traits::Storage;
    use openbrush::contracts::psp22::extensions::mintable::*;

    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(Default, Storage)]
    pub struct Contract {
        #[storage_field]
        psp22: psp22::Data,
    }
    
    // Section contains default implementation without any modifications
    impl PSP22 for Contract {}
    impl PSP22Mintable for Contract {}
     
    impl Contract {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(initial_supply: Balance) -> Self {
            let mut _instance = Self::default();
            _instance._mint_to(_instance.env().caller(), initial_supply).expect("Should mint"); 
            _instance
        }
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn mint_to(&mut self, account: AccountId, amount: Balance) -> Result<(), PSP22Error> {
            self.mint(account, amount)
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute "mint_to" message by the caller of contract executed account, it's OK
[image]

But when I execute "mint_to" message by the caller of the other account, the error occurs.

[image]

I don't understand why this error happen.

I would be glad if someone could tell me what it is.

Comment: Does the calling account (test2) have enough funds?

Answer (score 1):

The error likely happens because your `test2` account does not have enough funds to pay for the storage deposit.

For `pallet-contracts` / ink! the caller always needs to pay a deposit for any storage that will be created on-chain with the invoked message. This deposit is returned to whoever frees up the storage again.

You should check in `polkadot-js` if your account has enough funds.

Comment: Thank you!

Your answer is correct! You're a big help, thank you!